# Reload ~USER-PROFILE/chrome/userContent.css without restarting Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, debian

How do I reload ~USER-PROFILE/chrome/userContent.css without restarting Firefox? In other words, how do I apply the changes brought by the modifications of ~USER-PROFILE/chrome/userContent.css without restarting Firefox?

I'm running Firefox Developer Edition 96.0b3 on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following note in
[Bug 1409065 - Reload userChrome.css without restarting](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1409065) :

> changes in userContent.css take effect when opening a new tab or window.

Do note that all instances of the website(s) for which you're modifying the CSS must be closed before you can reopen them and see the changes take effect. This does not apply to windows or tabs that are open under other user profiles or in private mode.

So, for example, if you have example.com open in two tabs, you must close those two tabs before reopening example.com, or else you will see no change.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that. God bless you.